# Why am I getting 'Failed to chmod' with SQLite on Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm getting the warning messages **'Failed to chmod'** and **'chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)'** when I execute my app on my Android phone. The code below occurs them.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/my_data.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

1. **With a path** like above, I get the warning. But without a path, no warning.
2. Warning with my phone, but no warning with **Genymotion**.
3. Even though the warning occurs, the app **works fine**.
4. My phone is Samsung Note2 and the android version is 4.4.2. The android version of the emulator is 4.3.

**May I ignore the warning?**

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that its failing because you are opening the database in the default location, while creating the database in another place? Instead of using "/sdcard/", try:

```
String sdpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "my_data.db";
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(sdpath, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```